# aggregate(Equal to) to bit operator in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I want to fetch data where Max(isPresent) == 1.
isPresent is my bit column

```
SELECT EmpID FROM EMPtable where Max(isPresent) = 1
```

How can I Achieve this one.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that there are multiple rows per employee in `EMPtable` in spite of its name, and so you can't simply say `WHERE isPresent = 1` because it would return too many rows.

You can convert it to a different type first (but you need to group in some way, otherwise you'll still get multiple rows per employee):

```
SELECT EmpID FROM dbo.EMPtable 
GROUP BY EmpID
HAVING Max(CONVERT(tinyint,isPresent)) = 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT EmpID FROM dbo.EMPtable AS e
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EMPtable
    WHERE EmpID = e.EmpID AND isPresent = 1)
GROUP BY EmpID;
```

Or:

```
WITH e AS (SELECT EmpID, pos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY EmpID)
  FROM dbo.EMPtable
  WHERE isPresent = 1)
SELECT EmpID FROM e WHERE pos = 1;
```

The method you use depends on what else you expect to return along with the `EmpID`. Here is [an example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OdNPP08Y).

Though this is largely a variation of [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps something as simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID FROM EMPtable where isPresent = 1
```

Comment: I was assuming they may need to return more than just the EmpID.